# How to reference a csproj using csc?

Tags: c#, csc

Using csc how can I reference another project's source?

If I have my own `.csproj` for a hefty project that depends on another, and am compiling the dependent with `dotnet build` rather than `csc` I can add

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\MyAPI\MyAPI.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

To the csproj file, but what about in the case of writing a single `.cs` file?

```
csc test.cs /reference:../MyAPI/MyAPI.csproj
```

doesn't work because

> error CS0009: Metadata file '/Users/me/MyAPI/MyAPI.csproj' could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata.
> test.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyAPI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: csc doesn't know about project files. Basically, you'd need to build your other project first, and then reference the output with csc.

Comment: MSBuild sequences that in the project build order so that the referencing project is built latter and the csc commandline references the output generated earlier.